# Redefinir id's de divs por números em ordem

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Sou bastante leigo em JavaScript e jQuery, e estava precisando alterar os id's das divs em ordem numérica.

Por exemplo:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="8"></div>
<div id="11"></div>
```

e transformar em:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
```

Alguém sabe um método pra fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando JavaScript puro você pode criar um *nodelist* com `document.querySelectorAll("div")` e depois iterar com `for` alterando os id's:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for(var x = 0; x < divs.length; x++){
   divs[x].id = x+1;
   
   // linha abaixo só para visualização
   console.log(divs[x].outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="8"></div>
<div id="11"></div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, irei utilizar

Answer (score 0):

Podemos utilizar a função `each` (função que efetua um loop) para percorrermos todas as div do nosso HTML.

Essa função irá realizar um loop em todas as divs (nós especificamos que será nas divs no comando `$(div)`), e temos também o índice atual do loop no parâmetro `index`, e o elemento atual (div atual) no parâmetro `element`. Agora basta definirmos o novo valor para nosso atributo `id`, utilizando a função `attr()` do JQuery.

```
$('div').each(function(index, element) { 
    // Já que o índice começa em zero então vamos definir o novo id como índice + 1
    $(element).attr('id', index + 1);
});
```

Você pode ver o exemplo funcionando aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/76342/

Comment: Obrigado, esse método funcionou também